# Adding momentary switch (push-button) to NodeMCU

Tags: nodemcu

I want to add 2-pole momentary push-button (switch) for my covers.

Integration goes through a NodeMCU and ESPHome.

I'm having a hard time understanding the schematics for this switch:

[image]

I'm not sure how to connect the inputs/outputs to a NodeMCU in order to have a response in my logs.
(Only one pin for example D1 to be reactive when I hold my push button.)

Comment: Do you intend to connect your NodeMCU to the line voltage?  Your example circuit shows how to connect a reversible motor to line voltage (like the power outlets in your home.)  Are you just trying to connect the switch to your NodeMCU, but without powering the motor?

Comment: What are your "covers?"

Comment: Are you legally allowed to do mains voltage electrical work? If not, or don't know to wire it, I suggest being extremely careful, as if you manage to burn your house down, the insurance company might not cover it.